# Where and how can I get dataset of patient narratives on the internet to predict diseases?

Tags: releasing-data

My aim is to create a trained model for predicting diseases. I need data set consisting of the following fields:

1. Causes of the Disease
2. Pathogenesis (the mechanism by which the disease progresses)
3. Age
4. Gender
5. Symptoms of the Disease
6. Damage caused by the Disease
7. Organ Type (e.g. Heart Disease, Liver Disease, etc.)